# Are these two List initializations identical?

Tags: c#, list, initialization, initialization-list

I want to convert

`var aList = new List<string>(new string[] { "elem1", "elem2", "elem3" });`

initializations into

`var aList = new List<string>() { "elem1", "elem2", "elem3" };`

in our source code. I believe that the latter doesn't have unnecessary array creation and array -> List conversion. Or the former has too? Or the compiler optimize it out anyway? Can I face any undesirable side effects (or lack of side effects) later?

The project uses .NET 4.

Comment: compiler won't optimize it, because it's implemented functionality of List (that it has constructor with IEnumerable parameter). So it will be converted and nothing bad should happen.

Comment: [http://www.dotnetperls.com/initialize-list](http://www.dotnetperls.com/initialize-list) says interesting things. My second variation compiles to the one what Shlomo says (Add calls). The array variation maybe more optimal: "copies an external array to the internal buffer of the List at runtime. This avoids unnecessary resizing of the List buffer."

Comment: So there's no unnecessary array creation as I state in my question it seems.

Comment: First I was afraid to ask such "simple" question, but it was worth it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not entirely equivalent.

1. In the first case you're creating a new array, then passing that to the `List<T>` constructor, which will create it's own internal array of the same size and invoke the source array's `CopyTo` method to copy items out of the source array and into it's internal array.
2. In the second case you construct a new `List<T>` with an initially empty array (of size `_defaultCapacity = 4`), and then invoking the List's `Add` method, which can cause the internal array to be resized several times as it's adding elements.

So in the first case, you benefit from not having to resize the List's internal array, as well as calling the potentially more efficient `CopyTo` method, rather than an iterative `Add`, at the cost of having to create two arrays in memory at once.

Here's one thing you could do to avoid creating two arrays *and* ensure you don't have resize the list's internal array:

```
var aList = new List<string>(3) { "elem1", "elem2", "elem3" };
```

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this for production code, due to the magic constant `3`, but then again, you've already got three other magic constants there anyway.

Comment: [http://www.dotnetperls.com/initialize-list](http://www.dotnetperls.com/initialize-list) says the same. Given that I don't have anything finicky, so there are really just string literals as elements the array version can be more optimal although a tiny bit longer. Interesting.

Comment: Note that for numbers of elements this small, the performance difference is unlikely to matter (perceptibly).  Of highest importance is correctness and readability.  They are all correct, so it simply comes down to readability/maintainability.  If the lists are large enough that the performance actually matters you almost certainly shouldn't be defining them in code; the data ought to exist in a file/database or something like that.

Comment: @CsabaToth I haven't run any actual tests, but I'd guess you'll have significantly improved time performance with the first method if your array is large (given the cost of resizing and `CopyTo` method likely being more efficient) -- but then again the cost in terms of memory is greater, too.

Comment: Also, if the code is called many times (for example during a page UI initialization), then it can matter somewhat. But maybe Servy is right too. Most of the initializers are 2-3 elements long.

Comment: I certainly won't go with any magic number (anti-pattern). I'll choose between the two I mention. Most probably I leave the source unchanged.

Comment: @CsabaToth When in doubt, optimize for readability. Personally, I prefer the second option.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I agree, I like clarity, but when in source control I think I don't disturb the source. This is too low gain in terms of readibility to convert from the array to the 2nd version.

Answer (score 1):

The latter gets compiled into:

```
aList = new List<string();
aList.Add("elem1");
aList.Add("elem2");
aList.Add("elem3");
```

The constructor looks like it is doing something similar to this (with some error handling):

```
foreach(var t in items)
    Add(t);
```

In otherwords, the array creation is unnecessary. For a micro-optimization, it is probably better to optimize as you're suggesting. However, in reality, your results won't differ much.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into that.

Comment: Maybe I should have asked my question this way: which initialization is more optimal in terms of runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If converted code will be like next:

```
var aList = new List<string>(3 /* !capacity specified */) { "elem1", "elem2", "elem3" };
```

It does not have an "unnecessary array creation" (in case, when you specify more than List<>::_defaultCapacity items).

With three (or four) strings you code also does not have an "unnecessary array creation", because _defaultCapacity == 4.

In other words, in the second code (with collection initializer without capacity specified) internal List<>`s array can be recreated a few times.

Comment: Yes, it turns out that there's no unnecessary array creation. That version probably even more optimal.